# How to stream an hdfs location for all files and write to another hdfs location simultaneously

Tags: pyspark, hdfs, azure-data-lake, azure-databricks

I have around 20K JSON files in parquet format in one hdfs location.
My Job is to stream the location and read all the files in a dataframe, followed up by writing the same in another hdfs location.

Can someone please suggest how can I do that. I am using Azure Databricks platform and pyspark to achieve this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if you want to do it in a "streaming" way or in "batch" mode. However, you can do it using streaming capabilities and trigger the job for once.

```
    (spark
.readStream # Read data as streaming
.schema(USER_SCHEMA) # For streaming, you must provide the input schema of data
.format("parquet")
.load(PARQUET_ORIGIN_LOCATION)
.writeStream
.format("delta")
.option("path", PARQUET_DESTINATION_LOCATION + 'data/')  # Where to store the data
.option("checkpointLocation", PARQUET_DESTINATION_LOCATION + 'checkpoint/')  # The check point location
.option("overwriteSchema", True)  # Allows the schema to be overwritten
.queryName(QUERY_NAME)  # Name of the query
.trigger(once=True)  # For Batch Processing
.start()
)
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I want to do it in a streaming way.
I want to know is it possible to do it without pre-defining the schema.
Because I have all the source parquet files in same hdfs location but after streaming I want to store it in target location using five different schema. This is the problem I am facing. Is there any wayaround to this problem